# Line and Letter Spacing in CSS

Tags: css

I've been working with a designer on a project. This designer sadly got really ill and is in a hospital. I'm working to take the design and convert it to HTML/CSS. Before leaving, the designer gave me some information regarding some of the text. For the text, I was told:

*Font Face: Arial, Tracking/Letter-Spacing: 72, Leading/Line-Spacing: 21*

I know in CSS I can create a class with this information. For instance, I can do

```
.myClass { 
  font-family:Arial;
  letter-spacing:72;
}
```

I have two questions though that I cannot figure out

1. The letter-spacing looks way too large when I do this. It does not look like the original design. Is there some unit information that I need to add? Is there a standard unit that I should be aware of?
2. How do I get a line-spacing of 21(unit?) in CSS?

Thank you!

Comment: you can try different units like em, px, pt or %.

Comment: I posted the true--no guessing-game--answer for tracking below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track, you just need to add units. It sounds like the `72` is defaulting to being 72 times the normal – which is a huge amount of space. At a wild guess, you may want to try percentage for the letter spacing, and pixels for the line spacing, like so:

```
.myClass {
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1.72;
    line-height: 21px;
}
```

In my opinion, using anything other than `%` and `px` above would result in unsensible values. However, if that's not correct then have a play with the units, or even the values. Have you got an image of what the page should look like to guide you?

Comment: percentage values for letter-spacing are not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Tracking values in Photoshop are actually in thousandths of ems;  Photoshop doesn't kindly specify this to the designer. So 72 = (72 / 1000)em = 0.072em.  That will give you true pixel-perfection and make your designers sing your praises.

Leading is simply in pixels.

Answer (score 3):

for leading it's

```
.myclass {line-height: 21px}
```

line-height can have units like px or em, used without the unit, which is the ususal way you see it - it's a percentage of the font-size so for example if the font-size: is 10px and you specify a line-height of 2 the line height will be 20px

see: [Unitless Line Heights](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/)

Answer (score 1):

Much better is to working with "em" as unit.

Following your spacing is always relative to your font size.

But to answer your question, I agree with Sam Starling and clairesuzy.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the designer what units they were referring to in the briefing. Everything else is just speculation. *Then* it's worth looking into how to implement the unit in CSS.

Comment: @Unicorn, the asker said they couldn't ask the designer. They need help in speculating.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the units as others suggest. If you've got a PSD you can work it out from there.

Personally I get some designs where I can't get the unit size, normally because the text is rastered or I get a flat jpeg or something. In these situations I use firebug and [pixel perfect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/). This overlays the design onto the site I'm building and I can tweak the CSS accordingly.